# python ctype recursive structures

Tags: python, dll, recursion, structure, ctypes

I've developped a DLL for a driver in C. I wrote a test program in C++ and the DLL works fine.

Now I'd like to interract with this DLL using Python. I've successfully hidden most of the user defined C structures but there is one point where I have to use C structures. I'm rather new to python so I may get things wrong.

My approach is to redefine a few structures in python using ctype then pass the variable to my DLL. However in these class I have a custom linked list which contains recursive types as follow

```
class EthercatDatagram(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("header", EthercatDatagramHeader),
                ("packet_data_length", c_int),
                ("packet_data", c_char_p),
                ("work_count", c_ushort),
                ("next_command", EthercatDatagram)]
```

This fails, because inside EthercatDatagram, EthercatDatagram is not already defined so the parser returns an error.

How should I represent this linked list in python so that my DLL understands it correctly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You almost certainly want to declare next_command as a pointer.  Having a structure that contains itself isn't possible (in any language).

I think this is what you want:

```
class EthercatDatagram(Structure):
    pass
EthercatDatagram._fields_ = [
    ("header", EthercatDatagramHeader),
    ("packet_data_length", c_int),
    ("packet_data", c_char_p),
    ("work_count", c_ushort),
    ("next_command", POINTER(EthercatDatagram))]
```

Comment: "isn't possible (in any language)" - that's true about c/c++/java-style structs or classes, but in languages with algebraic data types it's not just possible but also very common. e.g. `data List  a = Cons a (List a) | Nil` in ML-family languages (ocaml/haskell/SML/etc).

Comment: In those languages it's still implemented as a pointer; the language just abstracts the details of the pointer away. A struct is a contiguous sequence of memory, of a fixed size (determined by the sum of its components' sizes), so to contain a copy of itself it would have to be larger than itself, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why

```
EthercatDatagram._fields_.append(("next_command", EthercatDatagram))
```

does not work is that the machinery that creates the descriptor objects (see the source of the [`PyCStructType_setattro`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c) function) for accessing the `next_command` attribute is activated *only upon assignment* to the `_fields_` attribute of the class.
Merely appending the new field to the list goes completely unnoticed.

To avoid this pitfall, use always a tuple (and not a list) as the value of the `_fields_` attribute: that will make it clear that you have to assign a new value to the attribute and not modify it in place.

Answer (score -2):

You'll have to access `_fields_` statically after you've created it.

```
class EthercatDatagram(Structure)
  _fields_ = [...]

EthercatDatagram._fields_.append(("next_command", EthercatDatagram))
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  It compiles and runs, but trying to actually use an instance of the class gives an error:  AttributeError: 'EthercatDatagram' object has no attribute 'next_command'

Comment: The correct answer is below, as posted by user9876

You must first declare the class with 'pass', then declare the fields in a second call.  Think of it as forward declaration.