# How to read/copy ctype pointers into python class?

Tags: python, variables, pointers, ctypes

This is a kind of follow-up from [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228158/python-ctype-recursive-structures) if this can help you.

I'm defining a few ctype structures

```
class EthercatDatagram(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("header", EthercatDatagramHeader),
                ("packet_data_length", c_int),
                ("packet_data", POINTER(c_ubyte)),
                ("work_count", c_ushort)]

class EthercatPacket(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("ether_header", ETH_HEADER),
                ("Ethercat_header", EthercatHeader),
                ("data", POINTER(EthercatDatagram))]
```

note that this is parsed correctly by python, the missing classes are defined elsewhere.
My problem is when I call the following code

```
packet = EthercatPacket()
ethercap.RecvPacket(byref(packet))
print packet.data.header
```

This is incorrect. As I understand the problem, data is some kind of pointer so it isn't (really) mapped to EthercatDatagram, hence, the parser doesn't know the underlying header field.

is there some way to read that field as well as any other field represented by POINTER()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it working

correct code was

```
print packet.data.header[0]
```

thanks to the 7 person who dared to look at the question

the google string for the answer was : python ctype dereference pointer
3rd hit

Comment: I've answered this question before on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The square-bracket notation is indeed correct.  For reference, here's a snippet from some ctypes code I recently made:

```
class Message(Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ("id", BYTE), ("data", POINTER(BYTE)), ("data_length", DWORD) ]
    def __repr__(self):
        d = ' '.join(["0x%02X" % self.data[i] for i in range(self.data_length)])
        return "<Message: id = 0x%02X, " % (self.id) + "data_length = " + str(self.data_length) + (self.data_length > 0 and (", data: " + d) or "") + ">"
```