# Can Python ctypes.Structure contain itself?

Tags: python, c, structure, ctypes

I have a C structure below:

```
struct msg {
uint_32_t msgid;
char * msgtext;
struct msg* next;};
```

I try convert it to Ctypes format:

```
class msg(ctypes.Structure):
  _field_=(('msgid',ctypes.c_uint32),('msgtext',ctypes.c_char_p), ('next',msg))
```

After this I get a error:

```
NameError: name 'msg' is not defined
```

Can Python ctypes.Structure contain itself? And how I can use it?

Comment: Structures can't contain themselves since they'd obviously have to have an infinite size. You need more indirection.

Comment: Please read the docs. There's a section on [Incomplete Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#incomplete-types). Also, the type of your `next` field should be `ctypes.POINTER(msg)`.

Comment: Thanks eryksun and others. https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#incomplete-types and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228158/python-ctype-recursive-structures is very useful