# Is it at all possible to create indirectly recursive ctypes.Structure types?

Tags: python, ctypes

This is not the same as [#1228158](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228158/python-ctype-recursive-structures) or [#28879604](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879604/can-python-ctypes-structure-contain-itself). It's similar, but with a twist.

It's trivial to create a recursive type referring to its own type:

```
A = type('A', (ctypes.Structure,), {})
A._fields_ = [('another_a', ctypes.POINTER(A))]
```

or, if you prefer:

```
class A(ctypes.Structure):
    pass
A._fields_ = [('another_a', ctypes.POINTER(A))]
```

Same thing. If they're not the same thing, do educate me!

But I'm trying to machine-translate C `struct`s and `typedef`s into `ctypes.Structure`s. I want the names and relations on the Python side to reflect those on the C side. If a function is returning a `uint32` that is `typedef`ed as `consumer_id`, I want the object on the Python side to have the more descriptive name. Now, here's a type of thing that occurs quite often:

```
typedef dummy_type official_type;
typedef struct dummy_struct {
    official_type *another_struct;
} dummy_type;
```

No matter how I twist and turn this, I can't realize this relation in Python. The intermediate names are *probably* not used anywhere, so at the moment we're going with the idea of detecting this situation and just making `official_type` a `ctypes.Structure` referring to itself. And maybe make `dummy_type` and `struct dummy_struct` types referring to themselves. On the binary level, on the C side, they'll all be equivalent.

But what I really want to do is this:

```
Struct_dummy_struct = type('struct_dummy_struct', (ctypes.Structure,), {})
Dummy_type = type('dummy_type', (Struct_dummy_struct,), {})
Official_type = type('official_type', (Dummy_type,), {})
Struct_dummy_struct._fields_ = [('another_struct', ctypes.POINTER(Official_type))]
```

Of course, this is not possible:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: _fields_ is final
```

I think what I'm trying to do is theoretically impossible, given the way `ctypes` works, but if anyone could tell me there's a way, I would be delighted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the same construction in python:

```
class official_type(ctypes.Structure):
    pass
official_type._fields_ = [("another_struct", ctypes.POINTER(official_type))]
first_instance = official_type()
second_instance = official_type()
first_instance.another_struct = ctypes.pointer(second_instance)
print first_instance.another_struct
```

`<__main__.LP_official_type object at ...>`

Ctypes has a funky struct finalization process, if you dig into the unit tests you'll find something like:

> Structure/Union classes must get 'finalized' sooner or later, when one of these things happen:
>
> 1. _fields_ is set.
> 2. An instance is created.
> 3. The type is used as field of another Structure/Union.
> 4. The type is subclassed
>
> When they are finalized, assigning fields is no longer allowed.

Perhaps your class definition using type messes the process up.

Comment: My fallback is to not copy the exact same type structure, but I'm curious if there might be some unexpected way that it's possible. The reason my example code cannot (as far as I understand!) work is, as you note, I'm touching `_fields_` after the type was inherited. If I were using `class`, the same thing would happen.

Comment: I ran into this problem when trying to `Structure > A > B > set _fields_ for B`. It had already finalized on subbing from A to B, but not while subbing from Structure to A.
My guess is that subclassing Structure is a special case which does not finalize it directly.

Comment: My impression is that Structure acts as a template class, which makes subclasses act with "magic" when you poke `_fields_`. But your case must have happened differently to get an error, perhaps you mean you tried to set `_fields_` for `A` after subclassing to `B`?

Comment: Well ctypes structs are defined in C, the ctypes module is just a very thin wrapper. Coincidentally, I did work around my problem with such a magic template class.

Comment: Marking this as the answer, as the answer seems to be "indeed, what you are asking for is theoretically impossible". :-)