# ctypes: how to define a ctypes.Structure for a C struct that references itself?

Tags: python, ctypes

In C, it is allowed to define a struct that embeds pointers to objects of the same struct that is being defined. For example, the following `node` struct implementation for nodes of a list

```
typedef struct node{
    void *val;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node;
```

embeds pointers `next` and `prev` that are of type `node*`.

Translating this naïvely into a Python `ctypes.Structure` class yields:

```
class NODE(Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ("val", c_void_p),
                 ("next", POINTER(NODE)),
                 ("prev", POINTER(NODE)) ]
```

However, python does not allow to make reference to a class (in this example, `NODE`) within its own definition (`NameError: name 'NODE' is not defined`).

How can I work around this?

PS: I attempted defining the `_fields_` attribute *after* the class definition

```
class NODE(Structure):
    _fields_ = []
NODE._fields_ = [ ("val", c_void_p),
                  ("next", POINTER(NODE)),
                  ("prev", POINTER(NODE)) ]
```

but this is not allowed because `_fields_` is tagged (?) as `final` in the ctypes.Structure base-class.  (`AttributeError: _fields_ is final`)

Comment: Actually answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228158/python-ctype-recursive-structures) makes the code run without errors, but the Python attributes are not bound with the C attributes. Hence it does not answer my question. Also, since then I found another solution that does not break the binding and which I would like to post as an answer here.

Comment: This is explained in the [ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#incomplete-types). If you look closely at the example, you can see that the forward definition does **not** define the `_fields_` attribute and is just a class that has the `pass` statement.